# Redirecting specific category to subdomain

Tags: categories, subdomains

I have a problem in following situation:

I have 2 separate **Wordpress 3.3.1** instances, main at `domain.com` and one of them (which consists of simple Q&A type site) is available from subdomain `forum.domain.com`. Now I have to merge them into one instance - to be able to share plugins, theme and posts (<-- that's important).

At this moment, `forum.domain.com` points to that second instance. I can quite easily get rid of it just by creating post categories for questions and displaying them accordingly. But then, my questions will have links like `domain.com/category/forum/question-subcategory/question` and I want them to be like `forum.domain.com/question-subcategory/question`. I've seen that there is a [WP Subdomains](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/) plug-in that does exactly that but it's not compatible with WP 3.3.1. I thought that should be possible with .htaccess rules but [this post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4384122.htm) seems to explain that it's not.

I considered using *WP Multi-site* feature but as far as I know, separate sites have separate tables in DB, thus they can't share posts (which is needed, as previously said).

Does anybody have any clue how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Can't vote up but really interested in replies to this! - Thanks

Comment: Sites in a multisite instance **can** interact with eachother. Refer to these functions: `get_current_blog_id()`, `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks for hints but finally, I had to abandon the idea of subdomain due to lack of working solution for this. I made separate categories for questions and used some hooks to display&operate on them properly. Thanks to the [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin, I now have `domain.com` (main blog) and `domain.com/forum/` (Q&A), and the latter seems to be different  site - with different headers, sidebars, logic, etc. from user's point of view (it's all on one instance, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled immensely trying to use subdomains for categories on my wordpress site. I tried a variety of plugins that were very buggy and eventually attempted writing my own. I kept running into additional problems left and right. Frequently I'd add new plugins that didn't function properly with the unconventional subdomain setup and I ultimately gave up on trying to make this work.

The only "solution" that I think might end up working is a wordpress multisite where each site holds posts for a given category then all sites are aggregated on a master site. This introduces another big heap of chores but I think it would actually function properly. It'd just be a pain in the neck.

Anyway, to all that read this post, **if** you do find a solution that works for you, please do chime in and let us know.